# How to prevent duplicates in generated sequences by using dif/2?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, failure-slice, prolog-dif

This question came up while answering [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333727/how-to-make-prolog-able-to-generate-all-possible-solutions-to-a-query) on (generalizing a bit) generating all sequences formed out of a finite set of elements with no duplicate occurrences.

As Boris rightly indicated in the comments, there are many existing solutions to this problem. However, I am interested in a solution that does not use an accumulator (i.e., a list of already picked elements against which a newly selected element is to be compared) but that uses `dif/2` statements instead.

To illustrate, in my following program I have 4 elements and, after 4 recursive calls, a couple of `div/2` statements which state that the 4 elements that have been chosen until now are pairswise dissimilar. From this one can deduce that it makes no sense to continue the recursion and look for a fifth element, since there are no elements left given the `div/2` statements. Is there a way to encode this 'knowledge' into the program so that it no longer loops?

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).
:- use_module(library(dif)).

sequences([]).
sequences([H|T]):-
  maplist(dif(H), T),
  between(1, 4, H),
  sequences(T).
```

Current, looping behavior:

```
?- sequences(X).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
...
X = [4, 3, 1, 2] ;
X = [4, 3, 2, 1] ;
<LOOP>
```

Comment: Do you want to have only lists of length 2 or more, or do you want a general solution?

Comment: @Boris I would like the program to work for lists of arbitrary length / an arbitrary number of elements (cardinals in this case). The lower bound of 2 is indeed not necessary and may be generalized.

Comment: Isn't this identical to: for a set of size N, find all combinations with size 0 (or 1, or 2...) up to N? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Boris I agree that using an accumulator is a correct solution here. I used it in my solution to the original question that prompted the current one. My point is that I *know* there are are - say - N unique elements and I *know* that these are pairwise dissimilar (i.e., the `dif/2` statements), so my program should not loop since it already has enough knowledge.

Comment: @Boris I believe you are correct that my problem is identical to the one you describe. As a matter of fact, yours is more general. If it can be solved with `dif/2` and without accumulator that would automatically answer my question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Tiny issue to start with — the name: `sequences/1` suggests a list of sequences (whatever a sequence is), it should be rather `sequence/1`.</sup>

You are demanding quite a lot of a poor Prolog system: You are demanding stronger consistency. At any price, I presume.

My immediate reactio (use `library(clpfd)`!) does not work, let's see why

```
?- length(Xs,N),Xs ins 1..4, all_distinct(Xs).
```

It loops just as much as your version, which can be best seen with this [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
?- length(Xs,N), false, Xs ins 1..4, all_distinct(Xs).
```

So already `length/2` alone is wrong. Maybe I reiterate to your program, and try to identify why your program does not terminate:

```
sequences([]) :- false.
sequences([H|T]):-
  maplist(dif(H), T), false
  between(1, 4, H),
  sequences(T).

?- sequences(X), false.
```

Our dearest declarative poster child `maplist/2` caught *in flagranti*! OK, maybe we should not be that harsh. After all, honest non-termination of a predicate is always preferable to an unscrupulously unsound or incomplete hack.

What we need to understand is that `all_distinct/1` requires the length of the list to be known, and all domains must be present, too.

```
sequence(Xs) :-
   sequence_aux(Xs, []).

sequence_aux([], _).
sequence_aux([X|Xs], Ys) :-
   X in 1..4,
   all_distinct([X|Ys]),
   sequence_aux(Xs, [X|Ys]).

 ?- sequence(X).
```

Now terminates.

@mat may note that `all_distinct([_])` might be removed.  Maybe even more than that.

If you do not like this solution because it uses an extra argument, you will need to implement a safer `maplist/2`.

```
fmaplist(C_1, Xs) :-
    freeze(Xs, fmaplist_aux(C_1, Xs)).

fmaplist_aux(_C_1, []).
fmaplist_aux(C_1, [X|Xs]) :-
   call(C_1, X),
   freeze(Xs, fmaplist_aux(C_1, Xs)).
```

Now you can use your original program verbatim.  But I do not feel very good at it. Understanding the precise borders of non-termination in a program with freeze is much more difficult.

---

As an aside: you might try to get correct variable names in SWI for answer substitutions because the `_G772`-like numbering does not permit to re-paste an answer back into the toplevel shell and get correct results.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer, but too long for a comment:

Your problem is that you want to keep your elements as facts. Put them in a list, and you can use `select/3` to take out an element from that list. As long as you keep them as facts, this is going to be more round-about than it needs be (I feel). A sorted list (a cardinal has an order, usually) is a perfectly good way to represent a set in Prolog.

EDIT:

Since I am still not sure if I understand your question, here is the actual answer to the question I think you are asking:

Don't use `dif/2`, because it is not necessary. Instead, for example:

```
combination([], _).
combination([X|Xs], Set) :-
    select(X, Set, Set0),
    combination(Xs, Set0).
```

Here, you would have to build your initial set using `setof/3`, or another predicate that builds a list of all solutions. I fail to see the need for `dif/2` if you can use a list and `select/3` from it.

But if you really insist, I would do it like that:

```
set_el(a).
set_el(b).
set_el(c).

set_el_combination(Combination) :-
    set_el_combination_1([], Combination).

set_el_combination_1(C, R) :-
    reverse(C, R).
set_el_combination_1(C0, C) :-
    maplist(dif(X), C0),
    set_el(X),
    set_el_combination_1([X|C0], C).
```

You will notice that the order of solutions is different (proper lexicographical order), as to be expected. You can use a difference list if you want to avoid reversing at the end. I am sure this could be also written as a DCG.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Based on your suggestions I have been able to improve the formulation of my question quite a bit (dropping DCGs as well as the "2 or more" requirement). I am also no longer keeping the elements as facts. I hope my questions is a bit clearer now.